# Line graph won't start at 0

Tags: graph, powerbi

Please help. I am trying to recreate a tableau report that has a running total per day for the year. I have a running total that works per month so the top graph works great. How do I recreate the bottom graph and have it start from 0?

[Graph needs to combine years into one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1V1j.png)

[How it Needs to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7KhU.png)

Comment: I was able to get them to start out at 0 but now they graph according to the data's year. I do need each year but want to combine them all into only months. How do I combine these into 12 months but separate from year? I have to have year in the formula to single out each year. here is the formula I use for 2 years ago data
2 Years Ago Running Total = CALCULATE(
    (CALCULATE([Running Total], Sales[Created Year] = YEAR(TODAY()) - 2)),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Sales[createdon]),
        Sales[createdon] <= MAX(Sales[createdon])
        && YEAR(Sales[createdon]  = YEAR(TODAY()) -2
    )))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.